# how to use google user id in entities - python appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I create an entity like so:

```
company = dbDatafile(usOwner = user)
company.name = self.request.get("name")
company.put()
```

where user is the Google User account. Now when I try to search on that user like:

```
datafiles = dbDatafile.gql("WHERE usOwner = '%s'" % user.user_id())
```

assign to a jinja2 template var:

```
template_values = {
    'datafiles': datafiles
}
```

and output to html:

```
{% for datafile in datafiles %}
    >>>{{ datafile.name }}         chevrons to indicate any looping
{% endfor %}
```

i get no output.

The data is there in the admin dashboard but I can't access it. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `usOwner` is a UserProperty, you need to use `USER()` in GQL:

```
datafiles = dbDatafile.gql("WHERE usOwner = USER(:1)", user.email())
```

Also remember always to use placeholders, not string interpolation - just because it's not SQL, doesn't mean it's not vulnerable to injection.

Comment: I believe an attacker could, at worse, inject more filters into the GQL; without a `;` operator or any way to do anything but `SELECT` queries, there's not much danger (although I'd love to be proven wrong.)

Comment: No, indeed there's not that much they can do, especially in this case: but better to be protected than not.

Comment: Also, every opportunity to inject is valid input that you're mistreating.

Answer (score 0):

OK this isn't strictly answering my question but a slight workaround. I decided to use the parent feature so my code now looks like this:

```
company = dbDatafile(parent=db.Key.from_path('user', user.user_id()))
company.name = self.request.get("name")
company.usOwner = user
company.put()


datafiles = dbDatafile.gql("WHERE ancestor IS '%s'" % db.Key.from_path('user', user.user_id()))
```

Not sure if this is ideal but it works and is compatible with the High Replication datastore.